# Swift Bridging header expected ';' after method prototype

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I've created a new Swift project and decided to make use of the "[Bridging Header](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)" feature of XCode to use several Objective-C files.

It all worked fine, except for one specific header, which when included in the bridged, throwed:

```
<unknown>:0: error: something/include/SomeClass.h:269: expected ';' after method prototype
```

Looking at the line, the code looked something like:

```
-(void) searchField:(NSString*) searchField
         notBetween:(NSNumber*) number1
                and:(NSNumber*) number2;
```

If I change the word `and` to anything else (`qwerty`) the compile error goes away!
The same code works fine with an Objective-C project.

Thoughts?

Comment: I wonder if it's trying to do some clever auto-translation of parameter names like "andNumber", etc., and falling on its backside because it's got no name left after it's stripped the "and"? I know it does clever things like strip the "with" from initWithWhatever when translating initialisers. Is there documentation for the bridging header translator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug, fixed in Beta 5.

http://openradar.appspot.com/17110619

Answer (score 1):

`and` is a C(++) macro, defined in < iso646 >.

You shouldn't use C/C++/Objective-C keywords and macro names in your Swift code exported outside Swift. This is a rule of thumb of most languages when interacting with the C family.

Comment: It's not Swift code. It's ObjC code imported into a Swift project. Does it make sense that this method worked in a pure ObjC project?

Comment: Oh. All right, in the assistant editor, select "Preprocess" and have a look at your method. How does it look like?

Comment: "No Assistant Results" - Keep in mind if it matters, that this is a `.h` file, for which I don't have the `.m`. The source is closed in a binary library.